# Synchronize Active Directory from on-premise to cloud AD

Tags: active-directory, ldap, cloud

All,

We have a requirement to synchronize our client's AD to our AD running on hosted environment (connected by a VPN). Also we would like to filter a specific set of users (say their group memmbership) and synchronize only those with the AD on cloud.

Any best practices or suggestion you could guide me to?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general server tech support.

Answer (score 0):

If by "Cloud" you mean Azure AD. You can use DirSync tool to synchronize your AD. This tool is simple to use and does the job.

Here's a [article](http://www.codetwo.com/admins-blog/sync-premises-ad-office-365/) talking about it.

Comment: Its not Azure AD, but just another Active Directory in an hosted environment outside the realm/domain of the on-premise Active Directory. Effectively we need to sync the hosted environment AD with the on-premise one.